# How I can use a components many times in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a react native app and I want to add a list of cards in this. But i not want to write code for every card. I just want that i write once a code and it render for all items.

Comment: I wish you'd ask a clearer question. If possible include an easily reproducible code example. Here are some helpful tips on how to construct better questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple map function or else use Flatlist component in react-native

refer https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist for Flatlist component